# Running C for arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, c, avr-gcc

Is there a compiler that I can use to run C on an arduino or any other way so that I can upload C programs to my arduino?

Comment: What do you mean by "run C"?  You can just compile them into your sketch.

Comment: How can I do that? I'm not very familiar with arduino software.

Comment: You basically do that every time you compile a sketch. The Arduino compiler is C++, which is backward compatible with C for the most part.

Comment: [*!!!**](https://authordylanhearn.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/so-you-think-youre-confused-about-quantum-mechanics-9.jpg) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should look into here
https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Build-Process

Arduino uses avr-gcc compiler. Basically, it is a C compiler.

There is an step by step on how to customize this process using an avr-gcc compiler of your own here
http://www.wikihow.com/Write-Arduino-Software-in-C

But I best recommend you downloading the arduino IDE on the official website to get things going. It has all the serial pairing stuff you don't really need to know to get started.

Hope it helps.

Comment: GCC is a C++ compiler? Anyway, most/any C++ compiler can compile C-code as C is basically a subset of C++ (Don't quote me on this though, it'll work, but it's not that trivial)